# Modeling Amoeba-Bacteria Interactions

Tags: r

I've been working on a project involving a model in R and I've run into a bit of a stumbling block. The model I'm creating is bifurcated into two components - the water tap and the water trough. I'm having some trouble incorporating certain biological interactions into my equations.

Specifically, I'm aiming to represent the following process: My amoeba is able to ingest bacteria. After the bacteria have been ingested, they can attack the amoeba and potentially cause its death. The ingested bacteria can then be released back into the water as free bacteria.

I'm struggling with how to represent these interactions within the model. Any suggestions or guidance on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

I tried this to represent with the Holling function `+ (θ * M_P * P_M )/(1 + θ * H_t*1)*K4`, where `K4` is the carrying capacity of intracellular bacteria

also

these are the equations:

```
dM <- M * g_M * (1 - M / K3) - πM * M - (M / V_trough) * D * NC - β * P * M + 
    (θ * M_P * P_M )/(1 + θ * H_t*P_M)*K4 + R * M_P *P_M

# Infected amoeba trophozoites
dP_M <- β * P * M + g_P * P_M * (1 - (P + P_M) / K_2)  - πP * P_M  -
   (P_M / V_trough) * D * NC - (θ * M_P * P_M)/(1 + θ * H_t*P_M)*K4 

# Intracellular Mycobacterium avium subsp. paratuberculosis
dM_P <-  g_MP * M_P *(1 - M_P/K4 * P_M) + β * P * M - 
    πMP * M_P + e * M_PC - n * M_P - R * M_P *P_M
```

when `Pm` (amoeba) ingest `MP` (bacteria) the bacteria attack the amoeba by Holling function then kill it and the inside bacteria then release by `R` to be `M` (free bacteria)

```r
# Parameters related to the killing precess of trophozoites by intracellular Mycobacterium avium subsp. paratuberculosis
θ <- 0.01  
H_t <- 0.11  # Handling time
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not clear what your question is, nor whether this is appropriate for Stack Overflow (your question doesn't seem to be about programming, but about dynamical modelling ...).  There's a lot here. Can you explain what parts *specifically* you're uncertain of?

Comment: I am trying to model amoeba and bacteria interaction in both water tap and water trough. the amoeba flow from water tap to water trough and there it will find bacteria too. then the amoeba will feed on bacteria, however the ingested bacteria will resist digestion and grow and kill the amoeba and released to be free bacteria again in water trough. this is my code but I have errors explaining the amoeba bacteria interaction after ingestion and attacking

Comment: I explained it in a nother question too in different way to be clear